# Why do I get a 405 response for a delete on live but not on local Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

Extremely unsure about this one and I can't find any results that relate to the specific issue I'm getting via searching.

I have a Laravel project where comments can be posted and then people can like the comments. The DB table for the likes has the like ID, user ID and the comment ID.

ViewComment.vue - `removeLike` method runs if they have already liked the comment and click on the like button.

```
removeLike(){
  if(this.user){
    axios.delete('/api/likes/' + this.comment.likes[0].id).then((response) => {
    this.comment = response.data;
  }, (response) => {
    this.error = response;
  });
  }else{
    window.location.replace('/' + i18n.locale + '/login');
  }
}
```

api.php - Routes for liking

```
Route::bind('like', function($value) {
    return \App\Like::where('user_id', Auth::id() ?? 0 )->find($value);
});
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function($router) {
    Route::post('likes', 'LikesController@store');
    Route::delete('likes/{', 'LikesController@remove');
    Route::delete('likes/{like}', 'LikesController@remove');
});
```

LikesController.php

```
public function remove(Like $like)
{
  $like->delete();
}
```

Error message:

[image: Error message received from live version]

When I run the project on my local server liking and then unliking the comment works perfectly normal with no errors, when it's on live it instead comes up with a 405 error, I have looked it up and found that this means that it's incompatible with the routes but I don't understand how that can be the case when it works on local, surely it would show up on local as well and the delete is in both the comment view file and exists as a route in api.php. If this is due to an issue with how it's hosted how can I improve the project to work with the hosting or if there's a specific need when it's hosted in order for it to work please let me know. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `Route::delete('likes/{',` a valid route with a single curly brace? I can't find it mentioned in the docs. Try commenting that line out.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you are using the `auth` middleware, so it is probably failing because you are missing the CSRF token.

Comment: I assume it must be valid since it does work since it does work when I run it on  my local server and how can I find CSRF token?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that commenting that out doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your Apache config. Probably  `AllowMethods GET POST OPTIONS` needs tweaked.

Have a look at the docs here and see if that helps.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_allowmethods.html

Comment: Would this be on the host server or do I need to add it to public/web.config

Comment: it's your Apache, so nothing to do with your site. It works on your machine!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused, the link you provided mentions the source file as a .c extension but I can only find a .so extension file on my local server which I don't think is right, how does modifying this affect the production build?

Comment: this should be defined in your apache conf somewhere

Comment: I've updated it on my machine, rebuilt the project and redeployed it and it's still coming up with a 405 error. I'm using wampserver as my local server and the live server is an azure web app so is this a configuration that needs to be changed in the web app? Because I fail to see how changing my local apache httpd.conf file would change this.

Comment: I didn't realise you were on Azure. Azure disable PUT PATCH and DELETE. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/34407079-enable-patch-put-delete-verb-for-php-environ#{toggle_previous_statuses}

Comment: web.config:
`<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <...>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="PHP73_via_FastCGI" />
      <add name="PHP73_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <...>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>` same error, any ideas?

Comment: not sure tbh, but also i notice you should be running 64 bit php, but are only running the 32 bit version

Comment: ah, of course, I'll try that and see if that makes a difference

Comment: I've added this on and restarted the server, could this be due to database permissions instead?

Comment: I doubt it very much, 405 means an unsupported HTTP method on that particular endpoint